# Why can't I create an executable from my Python script?

Tags: python, py2exe

I tried to convert my Python script `CHAP.py` into an executable with `py2exe` in Python 3.10. This is what happens:

---

```
C:\Users\MiDy1\source\repos\CHAP_2> python setup.py py2exe
C:\Users\MiDy1\source\repos\CHAP_2\setup.py:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
  from distutils.core import setup
running py2exe

  58 missing Modules
  ------------------
? IPython.display                     imported from PIL.ImageShow
? PIL._imagingagg                     imported from -
? PyQt5.QtCore                        imported from PIL.ImageQt
? PyQt5.QtGui                         imported from PIL.ImageQt
? PyQt6.QtCore                        imported from PIL.ImageQt
? PyQt6.QtGui                         imported from PIL.ImageQt
? PySide2.QtCore                      imported from PIL.ImageQt
? PySide2.QtGui                       imported from PIL.ImageQt
? PySide6.QtCore                      imported from PIL.ImageQt
? PySide6.QtGui                       imported from PIL.ImageQt
? __builtin__                         imported from pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing
? __main__                            imported from bdb, pdb, pkg_resources
? _ast_gen                            imported from pycparser._build_tables
? _dummy_thread                       imported from cffi.lock
? _frozen_importlib                   imported from importlib, importlib.abc, zipimport
? _frozen_importlib_external          imported from importlib, importlib._bootstrap, importlib.abc, zipimport
? _manylinux                          imported from pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.tags
? _posixshmem                         imported from multiprocessing.resource_tracker, multiprocessing.shared_memory
? _winreg                             imported from pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs, platform
? asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy      imported from -
? cPickle                             imported from pycparser.ply.yacc
? cStringIO                           imported from cffi.ffiplatform
? c_ast                               imported from pycparser._build_tables
? cffi._pycparser                     imported from -
? collections.Callable                imported from cffi.api
? collections.Iterable                imported from pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing
? collections.MutableMapping          imported from pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing
? com.sun                             imported from pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs
? com.sun.jna                         imported from pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs
? com.sun.jna.platform                imported from pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs
? defusedxml.ElementTree              imported from PIL.Image
? dummy.Process                       imported from multiprocessing.pool
? dummy_thread                        imported from cffi.lock
? java.lang                           imported from platform
? lextab                              imported from pycparser._build_tables
? numpy                               imported from PIL.Image, PIL.ImageFilter
? olefile                             imported from PIL.FpxImagePlugin, PIL.MicImagePlugin
? ordereddict                         imported from pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing
? org.python.core                     imported from copy, pickle
? os.path                             imported from cffi.ffiplatform, ctypes._aix, distutils.file_util, os, pkg_resources, pkgutil, py_compile, pycparser.ply.yacc, sysconfig, tracemalloc, unittest, unittest.util
? packaging.version                   imported from PIL.ImageFont
? pep517                              imported from importlib.metadata
? pkg_resources.extern.appdirs        imported from pkg_resources
? pkg_resources.extern.packaging      imported from pkg_resources
? pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing      imported from pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.markers, pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? resource                            imported from test.support
? setuptools.extern.more_itertools    imported from setuptools.dist
? setuptools.extern.ordered_set       imported from setuptools.dist
? setuptools.extern.packaging         imported from setuptools.command.egg_info, setuptools.dist
? setuptools.extern.packaging.specifiers imported from setuptools.config
? setuptools.extern.packaging.tags    imported from setuptools.wheel
? setuptools.extern.packaging.utils   imported from setuptools.wheel
? setuptools.extern.packaging.version imported from setuptools.config
? thread                              imported from cffi.cparser, cffi.lock
? win32api                            imported from pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs
? win32com.shell                      imported from pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs
? yacctab                             imported from pycparser._build_tables
Building 'dist\CHAP.exe'.
Building shared code archive 'dist\library.zip'.
Copy c:\users\midy1\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\python310.dll to dist
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\select.pyd to dist\select.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_bz2.pyd to dist\_bz2.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_lzma.pyd to dist\_lzma.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd to dist\unicodedata.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd to dist\_hashlib.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_decimal.pyd to dist\_decimal.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_socket.pyd to dist\_socket.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd to dist\pyexpat.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_ssl.pyd to dist\_ssl.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_queue.pyd to dist\_queue.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_elementtree.pyd to dist\_elementtree.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_testcapi.pyd to dist\_testcapi.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd to dist\_ctypes.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd to dist\_tkinter.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_testinternalcapi.pyd to dist\_testinternalcapi.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_asyncio.pyd to dist\_asyncio.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_multiprocessing.pyd to dist\_multiprocessing.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_overlapped.pyd to dist\_overlapped.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\_uuid.pyd to dist\_uuid.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.cp310-win_amd64.pyd to dist\PIL._imaging.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\_cffi_backend.cp310-win_amd64.pyd to dist\_cffi_backend.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingtk.cp310-win_amd64.pyd to dist\PIL._imagingtk.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingcms.cp310-win_amd64.pyd to dist\PIL._imagingcms.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingft.cp310-win_amd64.pyd to dist\PIL._imagingft.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingmath.cp310-win_amd64.pyd to dist\PIL._imagingmath.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingmorph.cp310-win_amd64.pyd to dist\PIL._imagingmorph.pyd
Copy C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\_webp.cp310-win_amd64.pyd to dist\PIL._webp.pyd
Copy DLL C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\tcl86t.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\tk86t.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Users\MiDy1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs\libffi-7.dll to dist\
```

---

Then I wanted to start my executable and got this error:

---

```
PS C:\Users\MiDy1\source\repos\CHAP_2> cd .\dist\
PS C:\Users\MiDy1\source\repos\CHAP_2\dist> .\CHAP.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CHAP.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "PySimpleGUI\__init__.pyc", line 2, in <module>
  File "PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.pyc", line 178, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'site'
```

---

Does anyone know where this is coming from? Maybe I didn't install some packages or anything? I would be very grateful if you could help me out here.

Here's my `CHAP.py`:

---

```
# CHAP.py
import glob
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import ctypes


#reference white in LAB
whitepoint_L = 100
whitepoint_A = 2.6249468183253133
whitepoint_B = -1.8752341146301976

#gradient_border determines how harsh the picture is treated
gradient_border = 100

#Debug on (1) or Debug off(0)
debug_LAB = 0       
debug_dist = 0      
debug_RGB = 0       
debug_gf = 0       

#screensize and image dimensions
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
window_width = screensize/4*3
window_height = window_width/16*9
image_dim = window_width/2


def search_images(path):
    images = glob.glob(f'{path}/*.jpg') + glob.glob(f'{path}/*.png')
    return images

def load_image(path, window):

    start_time = time.time()

    try:
        original_image = Image.open(path)
        original_image.thumbnail((image_dim, image_dim))
        photo_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(original_image)
        
        window["original_picture"].update(data=photo_img1)
    except:
        print(f"Couldnt open {path}!")
        return -1

    try:
        width = original_image.size[0]
        height = original_image.size[1]
        ergebnis_image = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), color = 'red')

        original_pixels = original_image.load()
        ergebnis_pixels = ergebnis_image.load()

        for x in range(0,width):
            for y in range(0, height):
                original_R, original_G, original_B = original_pixels[x, y]
                ergebnis_R, ergebnis_G, ergebnis_B = get_resulting_RGB(original_R, original_G, original_B)
                ergebnis_pixels[x, y] = (ergebnis_R, ergebnis_G, ergebnis_B)

        photo_img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ergebnis_image)
        window["resulting_picture"].update(data=photo_img2)
    except:
        print(f"Couldnt create resulting picture!")
        return -1



    stop_time = time.time()
    delta_time = stop_time - start_time
    print(f"time passed: ", float("{:.03f}".format(delta_time)), "[s]")
    return 0
        
def get_resulting_RGB(original_R, original_G, original_B):

    if original_R < 25 and original_G < 25 and original_B < 25:
        return 0, 0, 0

    L, A, B = RGB_to_LAB(original_R, original_G, original_B)
    if debug_LAB: print("LAB: ", L, A, B)

    distance = calc_distance_in_LAB(L, A, B)
    if debug_dist: print("Distance: ", distance)

    resulting_R, resulting_G, resulting_B = get_gradient_color(distance)
    if debug_RGB: print("R: ", resulting_R, " / G: ", resulting_G, " / B: ", resulting_B)

    return resulting_R, resulting_G, resulting_B

def RGB_to_LAB(original_R, original_G, original_B):

    #normalize RGB
    original_R /= 255
    original_G /= 255
    original_B /= 255

    #linearize RGB
    original_R = linearize_RGB(original_R)
    original_G = linearize_RGB(original_G)
    original_B = linearize_RGB(original_B)

    #calculate XYZ
    X = (0.4124564 * original_R) + (0.3575761 * original_G) + (0.1804375 * original_B)
    Y = (0.2126729 * original_R) + (0.7151522 * original_G) + (0.072175 * original_B)
    Z = (0.0193339 * original_R) + (0.119192 * original_G) + (0.9503041 * original_B)

    #linearize XYZ
    X *= 100
    Y *= 100
    Z *= 100

    #reference whitepoint in XYZ
    ref_X = 95.05
    ref_Y = 100
    ref_Z = 108.899999

    #calculate t's
    t_X = X/ref_X
    t_Y = Y/ref_Y
    t_Z = Z/ref_Z

    #get functions
    f_X = which_f(t_X)
    f_Y = which_f(t_Y)
    f_Z = which_f(t_Z)

    #calculate LAB-coordinates
    L = (116 * f_Y) - 16
    A = 500 * (f_X - f_Y)
    B = 200 * (f_Y - f_Z)

    #return
    return L, A, B

def linearize_RGB(single_RGB):
    if(single_RGB <= 0.04045):
        linearized_RGB = single_RGB/12.92;
    else:
        linearized_RGB = pow((single_RGB + 0.055)/1.055, 2.4)

    return linearized_RGB

def which_f(t):
    #constants
    epsilon = 216/24389
    kappa = 24389/27

    #check which operation is necessary
    if t > epsilon:
        f = pow(t, 1/3)
    else:
        f = ((kappa*t)+16)/116
    
    return f

def calc_distance_in_LAB(L, A, B):
    delta_L = L - whitepoint_L
    delta_L_squared = pow(delta_L, 2)
    
    delta_A = A - whitepoint_A
    delta_A_squared = pow(delta_A, 2)
    
    delta_B = B - whitepoint_B
    delta_B_squared = pow(delta_B, 2)

    root_term = delta_L_squared + delta_A_squared + delta_B_squared

    distance = pow(root_term, 0.5)

    return distance

def get_gradient_color(distance):

    g_factor = float(distance / gradient_border)
    if debug_gf: print("gradient factor: ", g_factor)

    if distance > gradient_border:
        gradient_R = 255 
        gradient_G = 0
        gradient_B = 0

    elif g_factor < 0.5:
        gradient_R = int(255 * (g_factor / 0.5))
        gradient_G = 255
        gradient_B = 0

    elif g_factor >= 0.5:
        gradient_R = 255
        gradient_G = 255 - int(255 * ((g_factor - 0.5) / 0.5))
        gradient_B = 0

    return gradient_R, gradient_G, gradient_B

def main():
    elements = [
        [sg.Image(key="original_picture"), sg.Image(key="resulting_picture")],
        [
            sg.Text("Image folder: "),
            sg.Input(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="folder"),
            sg.FolderBrowse(),
        ],
        [
            sg.Button("prev"),
            sg.Button("next")
        ]
    ]

    window = sg.Window(title="CHAP", layout=elements, size=(window_width, window_height), element_justification='c')
    images = []
    location = 0

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break

        if event == "folder":
            images = search_images(values["folder"])
            if images:
                load_image(images[0], window)
                location = 0

        if event == "next" and images:
            if location == len(images) - 1:
                location = 0
            else:
                location += 1
            load_image(images[location], window)

        if event == "prev" and images:
            if location == 0:
                location = len(images) - 1
            else:
                location -= 1
            load_image(images[location], window)

    window.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: See https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/4968 and also https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe/issues/115

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how `py2exe` work and the execution file won't not find the `site.py` which come with Python. This module is automatically imported during initialization.

The only way I known is to remark the line `import site` from your `Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUIPySimpleGUI.py`, then it will be fine.

revise line from

```py
import os
import sys
import re
import site
import tempfile
import ctypes
import platform
```

to

```py
import os
import sys
import re
#import site
import tempfile
import ctypes
import platform
```

Note: After you remarked `import site`, you can not use the method provided by PySimpleGUI to upgrade from github. Of course, it will be fine after you remove the remark.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. What does "remark" mean tho?

Comment: Does import site mean I have to add a line of code saying "import site" like i import time for example?

Comment: Update as above, not to revise your code, but source code of PySimpleGUI.